# Unable to install Cucumber Eclipse Plugin. Getting errors in mid of installation

Tags: installation, cucumber

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2021-06 and trying to install Cucumber Eclipse Plugin from marketplace as well as offline after clearing the artifacts.xml file in the .p2 folder. However, in each try I am getting the same error-
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_Electrobot_eclipse_java-2021-06_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
Public key not found for -9147676190077153272.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
Public key not found for -9147676190077153272.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
Public key not found for 8122282445186051625.
OK

Could someone please help me to get the installation successful?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJa4W.png)

I tried installing the Cucumber Eclipse plugin in my eclipse IDE(Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2021-06). However I am not able to install the software successfully. Getting some error message everytime and installation fails.